# A result concluded by Dirichlet's theorem

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, fourier-analysis, analytic-number-theory

We know from the Prime Number Theorem (PNT) that

$$\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=1}^N \Lambda(n)= 1+ o(1),$$

where $\Lambda$ is von Mangoldt function. Now consider $ W \in \mathbb{N}$ and define

$$\tilde{\Lambda} (n)‎ :‎=‎
‎\ \frac{\Phi(W)}{W} \ln(Wn+1)  $$

if $Wn+1$ is prime and $0$ otherwise.$\Phi$ is the Euler function. I saw somewhere that by Dirichlet's famous theorem about primes in arithmetic progressions and the PNT, it can be proved that

$$\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=1}^N \tilde\Lambda(n)= 1+ o(1).$$

Would anyone please introduce me some references to read the proof?

Comment: It is not so much a consequence of Dirichlet's theorem and PNT, but the proof comes out of combining the proof of PNT with the $L$-functions and characters that Dirichlet had already used in his proof about 60 years earlier.  The technical details of this combination were worked out by de la Vallée-Poussin shortly after the proof of PNT.  You'll want to search for "Prime Number Theorem for Arithmetic Progressions".

Comment: @ErickWong Thanks.I searched but I found nothing. would you please help?

Comment: Did you sincerely find nothing? Literally searching for that exact phrase in Google results in at least 3 PDF proofs on the first page alone.  One of them by Soprounov is particularly simple at only 3 pages long.

Comment: @ErickWong yes I did. None of them was exactly the proof I want.

Comment: That is completely different from “I found nothing”, and completely different from your question which merely asks for references.  If you can’t specify exactly what proof you want, no one can provide any references.